# Python async functions

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

Hey I am kinda new to the all deal of async functions and await and all this other stuff and I am having a hard time learning it.
So my question is how do I save / return and save into a variable some calculated data from a function ?

I tried to do :

x = 0

async def func(name):
x = name

Comment: What issue are you encountering?

Comment: I am working on making a discord bot using the discord py module and I want to get a list of the members of a certain server's members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like a synchronous function.

Example:

```py
import asyncio

async def addition(lnum, rnum):
    sum = lnum + rnum
    return sum

async def main():
    var = await addition(1, 1)
    print(var) #2

asyncio.run(main())
```